# When citing a source should grammatical spelling and other non crucial errors be fixed?

Tags: discussion

In this answer: [Do expensive, "premium" speaker cables make a difference?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2849/do-expensive-premium-speaker-cables-actually-make-a-difference/2850#2850)

@jozzas cites a [source](http://consumerist.com/2008/03/03/do-coat-hangers-sound-as-good-monster-cables/) which writes `Db` instead of `dB`, jozzas copy pasted the source as is, with the Db error. Then a user suggested an edit with the change to `dB` and another edit that was not correct, so I changed the `Db` to `dB` myself.

Should to change spelling errors in the cited material if it doesn't change the meaning and substance of the citation?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic might be useful in such a case.